# Is current-when got deprecated in Ember 2.x.x?

Tags: ember.js

We are trying to keep the current route active when a child route is accessed from an another child route of same parent.

```
this.route('example', {path: '/example'}, function () {
  this.route('user', {path: '/:user1'});
  this.route('article', {path: '/:user1/:article'});
});
```

When I navigate from 'user' route to 'article' route, the 'example' route is not keeping the 'user' route selected button active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use `link-to`'s [`current-when`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkComponent.html#property_currentWhen). It allows to specify for which routes should that specific `link-to` be considered active. It is not deprecated.

Alternatively, if you want to do it with routing, you can change them to the following:

```
this.route('example', {path: 'example'}, function () {
  this.route('user', {path: ':user1'}, function() {
    // implicit index route
    this.route('article', {path: ':article'});
  });
});
```

You would move `user` to `user.index`, and `article` to `user.article`.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot have nested route. In example template I've tried giving {{link-to 'example.user' current-when='example.article example.user'}}Route{{/link-to}}. This isn't working for article template as it is not accessed from Parent template i.e.example

Comment: Why can't you have nested routes?

Comment: if you use current-when then i suppose you would want it to target the parent route?  ..otherwise, nesting routes i agree makes more sense.

Comment: I'm using didInsertElement in article route to make the link active and this works in all the scenarios.